# How to manually label ROIs in Training Image labeler?

Tags: matlab, roi

I am new to **Matlab**. 
I want to label several images to use in SVM training later on.  
I have decided to use `ROI` but i can't label my `ROIs`. 
 I have `objectBoundingBoxes` column but i want to have object column and not_object column seperately. Or should I do this by writing code instead of manually? 
But i do not have any idea about it.

[Matlab Page Link](https://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/label-images-for-classification-model-training.html)

In this matlab page they say click the Add `ROI` label, I have matlab student 2016a and i dont have this option.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this option comes with MATLAB 2016b.